# How to ignore this "Property 'methods' does not exist on type" in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON object, i want to get the "methods" (one of the properties in the JSON object), but the "methods" sometimes exist sometimes does not exist. How can I check if exist, then only run my function, if does not exist, it will not jump this error "Property 'methods' does not exist on type" in typescript.

No error

```
data = {
...
methods: [{ id:1, name:"abc"},{ id:2, name:"def"}]
...
};
if (this.data.methods) {
    // this for loop no jump any error
    for (let index = 0; index < this.data.methods.length; index++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Error

```
data = {
....
}
if (this.data.methods) {
    // this for loop jump error "Property 'methods' does not exist on type"
    for (let index = 0; index < this.data.methods.length; index++) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(this.data.hasOwnProperty('methods'))`

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Sorry, I think my question just now not very clear, I updated the question.

Comment: `if (this.data.methods)` should prevent the loop from executing if data does not contain methods. the problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because the type of the object is being inferred by the JSON structure. It's being inferred as NOT having a `methods` property, so trying to access a methods property even to check if it exists is not valid. It can't exist. You need to tell typescript this object can have that property before checking for referencing it.

There are a couple ways you can do this.

1. You can assign a type that you've defined to the JSON objects:

```
interface Data {
  methods?: { id: string, name: string }[]
}

data: Data = {
  ....
}

// this.data.methods exists now and can be checked
if (this.data.methods) {}
```

2. Use a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface Data {
  methods?: { id: string, name: string }[]
}

const hasMethods = (data: any): data is Data => Boolean(data.methods)

data = {
  ....
}

if (hasMethods(data)) {
  // this.data.methods exists now and can be checked
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, but is that a way to do without using the interface? because my for loop is doing assign the "methods" into a formArray.

Comment: @mic_test I don't understand the question. Maybe you can include the code your for loop is executing so I can better understand

Comment: it's okay, i think i just use interface to do it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unsafe but shorter if your are sure `methods` exists:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < (<any>this.data).methods.length; index++)
```